# ipysheet dropdown can only be added at cell level?

Tags: ipywidgets

For for ipysheet all of `row`, `column`, `cell_range` and `cell` methods have a parameter `choice` which can be used for generating a dropdown.
See https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkGut.jpg.

But it seems only cell works. See code below.
In https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fjqy.png, only the cell at row 1 and column 0 has a dropdown. while others, though specified a choice option, are not displaying the dropdowns.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```py
import ipysheet
sheet = ipysheet.sheet(rows=5, columns=4)
row = ipysheet.row(0, [0, 1, 2, 3], background_color="red", choice = ['1', '2'])
column = ipysheet.column(1, ["a", "b", "c", "d"], row_start=1, background_color="green", choice = ['1', '2'])
cell_range = ipysheet.cell_range([["hi", "ola"], ["ciao", "bonjour"], ["hallo", "guten tag"]],
                                  row_start=1, column_start=2, background_color="yellow", choice = ['1', '2'])
cell = ipysheet.cell(row = 1, column = 0, value = 'Tom', choice = ['Tom', 'Jerry'])
sheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work with the `column` function by also passing the type as `dropdown`.

I think the documentation is incorrect for that function as it says

[image: type description]

[api reference](https://ipysheet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#ipysheet.easy.column)

However it seems that just passing `choice` in argument is not working. You also have to pass the type as `dropdown`

Here we can see the difference between the two calls:

without the `type` argument

[image]

with the `type` argument

[image]

The latest will return a `Cell` object containing all the values for this column, you can use it to initialize your sheet:

[image]